# How to insert a select into a table with an auto increment parameter?

Tags: sql-server

I'm copying data from an old database to a new one and some things changed and I need to copy the reference key value to the other one. It's a one to one relation so the ID's should match hence why i wanted to use an auto increment but I can't figure out how to do it.

this is my query

```
INSERT INTO hMetodologiaProducao (TipoMetodologia, QTDMetodoProducao, IdArtigo)
SELECT hm.TipoMetodologia, hm.QTDMetProd, auto-increment
FROM FolhaRegisto.dbo.hMetodologiaProducao hm
WHERE hm.IdMetProd != 16 AND hm.IdMetProd != 17 AND hm.IdMetProd != 4 AND hm.IdMetProd != 5
```

how can i do this?

EDIT. The values i need on where auto increment is, is the identity value from another table, can be row number since seed started from 0 becaue it's a fresh new database

**UPDATE**

It's a bit hard to explain what i want to do but, this is basically what i want to do

```
INSERT INTO hMetodologiaProducao (TipoMetodologia, QTDMetodoProducao, IdArtigo)
SELECT hm.TipoMetodologia, hm.QTDMetProd, (Select IdArtigo From hArtigos)
FROM FolhaRegisto.dbo.hMetodologiaProducao hm
JOIN hArtigos ha ON ha.IdArtigo = hm.IdMetProd
WHERE hm.IdMetProd != 16 AND hm.IdMetProd != 17 AND hm.IdMetProd != 4 AND hm.IdMetProd != 5
```

I want to insert in the 3rd column the IdArtigo from anothter table, but this way it won't allow me because it says there's too many values.

I also tried using a join but I can't because the ID values are different and some rows will end up with wrong ID

**NEW QUERY**

I found out something that does almost what i need

```
INSERT INTO hMetodologiaProducao (TipoMetodologia, QTDMetodoProducao, IdArtigo)
SELECT hm.TipoMetodologia, hm.QTDMetProd, ha.IdArtigo
FROM FolhaRegisto.dbo.hMetodologiaProducao hm
CROSS JOIN hArtigos ha
WHERE hm.IdMetProd != 16 AND hm.IdMetProd != 17 AND hm.IdMetProd != 4 AND hm.IdMetProd != 5
```

However it's inserting all the values for each value from 1st table so it gives me foreign key constraint error, how can i do it so it repeats only once?

**Final Edit**

Possible solution, this does exactly what i wanted. I just used distinct so it doesnt repeat values, althought i'm not sure if this is correct to do

```
INSERT INTO hMetodologiaProducao (TipoMetodologia, QTDMetodoProducao, IdArtigo)
SELECT DISTINCT hm.TipoMetodologia, hm.QTDMetProd, ha.IdArtigo
FROM FolhaRegisto.dbo.hMetodologiaProducao hm
CROSS JOIN hArtigos ha
WHERE hm.IdMetProd != 16 AND hm.IdMetProd != 17 AND hm.IdMetProd != 4 AND hm.IdMetProd != 5
```

Comment: `IDENTITY` ([CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) IDENTITY (Property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)) or [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017); depending on your need?

Comment: well the values match the identity value of another table where the foreign relation is set. But I have no idea how to do it. I tried to do a select of the ID but it said there was too many values and i dunno how to do it one by one in a select insert into statement.  EDIT. Actually since it's a new database it can be row number since it's new and identity seed started from 0

Answer (score 1):

I think if I am right you want to insert values in `Identity` column. You can do it in the following way.

```
Create table MyTable (Id int identity(1, 1), Name Varchar(20))

Set identity_insert MyTable on
insert MyTable(Id, Name) values (1 , 'A'), (2, 'B')

Select * from MyTable
```

Comment: it's not identity column though, it's just a normal column with foreign key that connects to identity column on another table

Comment: @Jackal I think you should provide sample data and expected result with proper test case. Currently it is not being clear what you are trying to ask.